# Custom Coreplot Legend

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I'm having problem sort my data in Coreplot. I have a stacked barchart, which is A and B. These values are also the values in my plot. However, coreplot sort the data in someway.

```
for (int i=0; i<[privDataArray count];i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSNumber *a = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[[privDataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"rente"] floatValue]];
    NSNumber *b = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[[privDataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"aflossing"] floatValue]];
    [dict setObject:a forKey:@"a"];
    [dict setObject:b forKey:@"b"];
    [data setObject:dict forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

This is my data instance. So i need B to be on the bottom of a stacked barchart. But Coreplot places it on the bottom of the stack.

Now, my solution to this is simply change names for A and B and the problem is solved.

However; i need to create a custom legend:

```
-(NSString *)legendTitleForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index==0) {
        return @"Rente";
    else if (index==1) {
        return @"Aflossing";
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

This produces a really strange legend. It shows two colors of swatches with random string next to it.

My question is: How can i return NSStrings for an index, in other words how to create a custom legend?

Comment: I don't understand the first code block. Why doesn't the Core Plot datasource pull the data from `privDataArray` directly?

Comment: because the privdataarray is a completely different dataset which is used by a tableview in de previous viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

The `-legendTitleForBarPlot:recordIndex:` method is only needed if you want a separate legend entry for each bar in the bar plot. See, for example, the "Colored Bar Chart" in the *Plot Gallery* example app. Set the plot `title` to make a single legend entry for each plot.

Comment: i see. Is there any other way to customize the legend label?

Comment: Customize the legend how? What do you want to change from the default appearance?

Comment: I need to change the name of the labels. Since my barchart does the following: I have two bars, one has the name A and the other has B. What happens is that A gets put on bottom and on that is stacked B. What i need is B to be on the bottom and A to be stacked on that. I know this could be a problem of the mutabledictionary, since that is sorted by first letter. However, when i change b to Xb: the order of stacking is OK. So i basically need to change the label for B and then everything works fine :-)

Comment: Set the `title` on each plot to the text you want displayed on its legend entry. The legend entries are displayed in same order as the plots are added to the graph, i.e., the first entry corresponds to the first plot, etc.